# Falcor Model with Cache data from External Api

Tags: falcor, falcor-router

How will the json data sent over from external Api be cached into the Falcor-Model? Also, how to specify in the Model to hit the external Api again if data not present in the cache?

My doubt was partially answered in one of the posts:
[How does Falcor cache data in the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39667053/how-does-falcor-cache-data-in-the-server-side)

So now I understand that Falcor-Model cache works only at the client side, which is fine. But how will the Model work if the data is not present in the cache?

```
var model = new falcor.Model({source: new falcor.HttpDataSource('http://localhost/rating.json') });
  model.
    get("rating").
    then(function(response) {
      document.getElementById('filmRating').innerText = JSON.stringify(response.json.rating,null, 4);
    });
```

Here the response is a json object, which can be put into a Falcor-Model cache and stored globally in the client side. But how can the Model be triggered again if data not present in cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main advantage of using Falcor is that you should not have to care whether data is present in cache or fetched from the server, because `model.get()` which fetch all the data missing in the cache from the server by making an HTTP request.

So, the first `model.get(path)` query will fetch from server, and put response in cache. If you call `model.get(path)` again, it will be served from the cache.